# Modulo Time in SQL Server 2005 - Return data every n hours

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, date, modulo

I have something like this:

```
 SELECt *
   FROM (
        SELECT prodid, date, time, tmp, rowid
          FROM live_pilot_plant
         WHERE date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '3/19/2012', 101)
           AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '3/31/2012', 101)
         ) b
  WHERE b.rowid % 400 = 0
```

FYI: The reason for the convert in the where clause, is because my date is stored as a varchar(10), I had to convert it to datetime in order to get the correct range of data. (I tried a bunch of different things and this worked)

I'm wondering how I can return the data I want every 4 hours during those selected dates.  I have data collected approximately every 5 seconds (with some breaks in data) - ie data wasn't collected during a 2 hour period, but then continues at 5 second increments.

In my example I just used a modulo with my rowid - and the syntax works, but as I mentioned above there are some periods where data isnt collected so using logic like: if you take data every 5 seconds and multiple that by 4 hours you can approximately say how many rows are in between wont work.

My time column is a varchar column and is in the form  hh:mm:ss

My ideal output is:

```
  | prodid  | date       | time      |  tmp  |
  |    4    | 3/19/2012  | 10:00:00  |  2.3  |
  |    7    | 3/19/2012  | 14:00:24  |  3.2  |
```

As you can see I can be a bit off (in terms of seconds) - I more so need the approximate value in terms of time.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
select prodid, date, time, tmp, rowid
from live_pilot_plant as lpp
inner join (

select min(prodid) as prodid                     -- is prodid your PK?? if not change it to rowid or whatelse is your PK
    from live_pilot_plant
    WHERE date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '3/19/2012', 101)  -- or whatever you want
                   AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '3/31/2012', 101)  -- for better performance it is on the inner select
    group by date, 
    floor(                                       -- floor makes the trick
    convert(float,convert(datetime, time))       -- assumes "time" column is a varchar containing data like '19:23:05'
    * 6                                          -- 6 comes form 24 hours / 4 hours
    )

) as filter on lpp.prodid = filter.prodid        -- if prodid is not the PK also correct here.
```

A side note for everyone else who have date + time data in only one datetime field, suppose named "when_it_was", the group by can be as simple as:

```
group by floor(when_it_was * 6)                  -- again, 6 comes from 24/4
```

Answer (score 1):

something along the lines of the following should work. Basically create date + time partitions, each partition representing a block of 4 hours and pick the record with the highest rank from each partition

```
select * from (
select *,
row_number() over (partition by date,cast(left( time, charindex( ':', time) - 1) as int)  / 4 order by
date, time) as ranker  from live_pilot_plant
) Z where ranker = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming rowid is a PK and increased with date/time. Just convert time field to 4 hours interval number `substring(time,1,2))/4` and select MIN(rowid) from each of 4 hours groups in a day:

```
select prodid, date, time, tmp, rowid from live_pilot_plant where rowid in
(
select min(rowid) 
from live_pilot_plant 
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, date, 101) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '3/19/2012', 101)
           AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '3/31/2012', 101)
group by date,convert(int,substring(time,1,2))/4

)
order by CONVERT(DATETIME, date, 101),time
```